# How to add condition checks in eclipse plugin.xml file?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, plugin.xml

I need to hide a menu item (File -> Exit) that is not relevant to me. I could do this using `org.eclipse.ui.activities` extension. The following code works great:

```xml
<activity
         description="Capability to filter all menus not relevant to the product"
         id="com.xxx.productspecific.filter.menus"
         name="Common UI Filter for menus">
   </activity>
   <activityPatternBinding
         activityId="com.xxx.productspecific.filter.menus"
         isEqualityPattern="true"
         pattern="org.eclipse.ui.file.exit">
   </activityPatternBinding>`
```

Now I need to make this work based on some condition. I have a program argument (or command-line argument) "targetEnv=FDK". The menu should be hidden only when this argument is available. I tried the below snippet, but the menu items continue to be hidden no matter what I provide in the argument.

```xml
 <activity
     description="Capability to filter all menus not relevant to the product"
     id="com.xxx.productspecific.filter.menus"
     name="Common UI Filter for menus">
  <enabledWhen>
     <with
           variable="%targetEnv">
        <equals
              value="FDK">
        </equals>
     </with>
  </enabledWhen>
```

Is this the right way to use a program argument in plugin.xml?

Comment: The available variables are listed [here](https://help.eclipse.org/2020-03/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fworkbench_cmd_expressions.htm)